# JavaScript: How to Loop through JSON objects with jQuery in an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am having difficulty trying to learn this concept.

I have a JSON file with a list of hospitals, their address, hours and phone.

I want to make an AJAX call from JSON data and list the data onto the screen.

I can only get the first hospital to list, when I try to list the address only the address lists.

How can I write this using a loop that will list the objects and their properties?

Can someone explain this to me, please?

Please help -- thank you in advance.

JSON --

https://api.myjson.com/bins/b29r7

JS --

```
var url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/b29r7';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
}).done(function(result){
    var data = result.surrey;
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        $('#data').each(function(index, ele){
            $(ele).html(data[index].hospital);
        });
    }
}).fail(function(err){
    throw err;
});
```

HTML --

```
<p id="data"></p>
```

Comment: I think you're just looking for a loop over a JS object.

Comment: for starters, `$('#data').each(` should be `$.each(data, function (index, elec) {...`

Comment: @Adam that doesn't work.

Comment: Please update your question to ask something more specific if these comments / answers aren't helpful; you asked "How can I write this using a loop that will list the objects and their properties?" which @jencko shows you below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```js
var url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/b29r7';

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'GET',
}).done(function(result) {
  // JSON data array
  var data = result.surrey;

  // get DOM node to be parent of child list nodes
  var $data = $('#data');

  // iterate through each object in JSON array
  data.forEach(function(item) {

    // create an unordered list node
    var $ul = $('<ul></ul>');

    // iterate through all the properties of current JSON object
    for (var field in item) {

      // append list item node to list node
      $ul.append(`<li>${field}: ${item[field]}</li>`);
    }

    // append list node to parent node
    $data.append($ul);
  });
}).fail(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="data"></div>
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/L6j8n17j/4/**

Comment: Hi @MiguelMota thanks for the working example. Care to explain the set up to me? Please? For starters, I don't get why you wrote the function the way you did. Starting with-- data.forEach(function(item){...});

Comment: perfect. Thank you so much but i don't get your for loop set up. Is that new in ES2015? What is field and item as I do not see them defined. I tried to google this but wan't lucky with results.

Comment: @scrippyfingers `forEach` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach `for..in` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in .

Comment: @scrippyfingers `forEach` iterates through all items in an array. The parameter `item` is the current item it's iterating over. `for..in` iterates through all the properties of an object. `field` is just a variable name for the object key it's iterating over, `item` is the object, `item[field]` is the object property value.

Comment: As for the line $ul.append(`<li>${field}: ${item[field]}</li>`); 

Does ${ field } represent "interpolation"? I googled and found interpolation in JS with the syntax like so; #{ field } , so i am not sure.. @MiguelMota

Comment: @scrippyfingers those are template literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals . (note you have to use backticks). They allow you to interpolate variable values inside of a string. Whatever is inside a `${}` gets evaluated to a value. That line is creating a list item with content and appending it the unordered list.

Comment: oh ok, i got it!! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE :** This is more clear version. You can print your values in your html like this.

```js
 
  
            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/b29r7',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    data = data.surrey;
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                       html+='<span>'+data[i].hospital+'</span>';
                       html+='<span>'+data[i].address+'</span>';
                       //so on 
                    }
                    $('#data').html(html);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Could not get Data');
                }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='data'>

</div>
```

This should bring your values on the console and then you can use html function at the same time in the loop to display the data. Thanks!

Comment: im not trying to print to the console, this solution does not work.

Comment: @scrippyfingers please check now .. is it clear for you now ?

Answer (score 2):

as per requirement please try below code

```js
var url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/b29r7';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
}).done(function(result){
    var data = result.surrey;
    var i = 0;
    var hosData = "<table border='1'>";
    hosData += "<tr>";
      
       hosData += "<th>";
         hosData += 'hospital';
        hosData += "</th>";
        
       hosData += "<th>";
         hosData += 'address';
        hosData += "</th>";
        
        hosData += "<th>";
         hosData += 'hours';
        hosData += "</th>";
        
        hosData += "<th>";
         hosData += 'phone';
        hosData += "</th>";
        
      hosData += "</tr>";
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
      hosData += "<tr>";
      
       hosData += "<td>";
         hosData += data[i].hospital;
        hosData += "</td>";
        
       hosData += "<td>";
         hosData += data[i].address;
        hosData += "</td>";
        
        hosData += "<td>";
         hosData += data[i].hours;
        hosData += "</td>";
        
        hosData += "<td>";
         hosData += data[i].phone;
        hosData += "</td>";
        
      hosData += "</tr>";
    }
    hosData += "</table>";
    
    $("#data").html(hosData);
}).fail(function(err){
    throw err;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id="data">
 
 </div>
```